# Git merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

Есть репозиторий код с которого я заливаю на продакшен посредством **git pull** - получается большое количество конфликтов. Не могу никак нагуглить каким образом забирать изменения из репы, что-бы не происходило слияния. Т.е. вне зависимости от того как изменился код, приоритет должен отдаваться тем данным что в репе

Comment: У вас там на продакшне что, локальные изменения? Слияние чего с чем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команды, которые должны вам помочь

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Первая команда скачает все изменения, при этом не сливая их с локальными, а вторая сбросит все изменения до состояния ветки origin/master